# Magento2 Layout update with XML

Tags: magento-2.1, xml, layout-update

I want to move a block on my page.
its now located in the header and i want to move it to the panel header.

In the xml file of the extension, i see this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Interactivated_Customerreview::css/kiyohrating.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <block class="Interactivated\Customerreview\Block\Customerreview" name="top.kiyohmicrodata" as="top.kiyohmicrodata" template="Interactivated_Customerreview::microdata.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

What do i need to change to move this?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 comes with a move xml element

```
<move element="block.or.container.name" destination="destination.container" />
```

In your case it will singly be what ever is in your Magento_theme folder under layout